# Prevent PHP from parsing non-PHP files such as someFile.php.txt

Tags: php, apache, phpdoc

I just installed phpdocumentor, but received strange errors.  I finally tracked down the problem.

Phpdocumentor creates various files such as someFile.php.txt which contains PHP code, but aren't meant to be parsed.  Turns out, my server is parsing them.  I've also tested a file name called someFile.txt, and it isn't being parsed.

How do I prevent my PHP server from parsing files such as someFile.php.txt?

My server is PHP Version 5.4.20, Apache 2.2.15, and CentOS 6.4.  My `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` file is as follows:

```
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: What makes you sure it's being parsed? Why not add some code to echo a string in the .txt file and see if shows.

Comment: I'd be surprised if your server was parsing them as php.  Normally you have to tell Apache specifically *which* files *to* parse as php, and unless some crazy configuration is telling `.txt` files to be parsed as php, I suspect it's a different problem.

Comment: 'What makes you sure it's being parsed?'  Because I am getting PHP errors.  I tested the .txt file exactly as you suggested, and it displayed `echo(...` so I know it isn't being parsed.

Comment: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .txt .html .lol .hue`?

Comment: If i'm not wrong here, what you're saying is you are opening these files to be read, but it's improperly interpreting the code within the files? wrap it in `<pre>` and just do `htmlentities()`

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy.  In my apache config file, the only thing that relates to AddHandler is `AddHandler type-map va`.  Also, as I indicated, someFile.txt isn't being parsed.

Comment: @Daedalus.  Typically things like `Fatal error: Class 'c2' not found in /var/www/site1/html/testing/phpdoc_out/files/child/main.php.txt on line 17`.  It is happening because PHP is parsing the file, and can't find the file.  Note I am using spl_autoload_register, thus the reason I think why the error actually showed the file.

Comment: Perhaps its file permission is set to execute as a program. Did you check this setting?

Comment: @cale_b.  After seing your comment, I added "apache" to the question tags.  I guarantee they are being parsed.  What would cause that?

Comment: It's a default setting of Apache to take all file extensions into account. Remove the handler for .php and use a dedicated `<FilesMatch .*\.php$>` with `SetHandler` or `ForceType` instead. See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext and alternatively [Apache ignoring extension and executing other files through fastcgi](http://serverfault.com/q/205972)

Comment: @itsols.  `-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root       34 Dec 11 11:38 test.php.txt`.

Comment: @mario  Yikes!  This must be the problem.  How can I only be the only one experiencing it if it is the default Apache install?  Do I remove the handler from my Apache config file or the php.conf file in Apache?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that the default settings of CentOS Apache actually allow this and it is a [known vulnerability](http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2013/01/13/PHP-and-Apache-SetHandler-vs-AddHandler). In order to fix it, you will need to edit your Apache config settings. Your PHP settings are typically in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`. The default looks like this

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

We need to change it to

```
#AddHandler php5-script .php
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
AddType text/html .php
```

Restart Apache and that should be the end of parsing any file with an extension after `.php`

Now, that `$` is very important because this is using `regex` and within `regex` a `$` means "end of string". So that means the file has to END with `.php` (i.e. no `.php.txt`) to be parsed by PHP.

Comment: Thanks Machavity.  I added my php.conf file to my original post.  Thoughts?

Comment: Teaching myself something here (I've not fiddled with this file a ton directly). Apparently the `AddHandler` declaration is the problem because it never stops after `.php`. If you can afford to screw with your server settings for a second (sometimes there's no substitute for trial and error) try commenting out `AddHandler php5-script .php` and put the tag in my post above in and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Machavity.  I will do and post my results.  Please look at  mario's comment, and his link to the Apache documentation.  According to him, my results are exactly as expected for a default Apache install.

Comment: I actually found a [blog](http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2013/01/13/PHP-and-Apache-SetHandler-vs-AddHandler) directly on point about this so mario is right. Remi advocates doing just what I said in my last comment and mario is saying exactly the same thing

Comment: Thanks for your help Marchavity.  Yes, this worked.  Surprising it isn't a more common problem for others..

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem on CentOS 6.5, and I needed to fix this in a virtual environment where I don't have access to `php.conf`.

I used the following in a `.htaccess` file.

```
# Match anything that ends with .php.txt
<FilesMatch \.php\.txt$>
    RemoveHandler .php
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

I don't allow uploads by users, so I'm not worried about any security implications. I just wanted to get the `.php.txt` extension working. This did the trick.